# Google charts stacked column chart set colors conditionally by especific value

Tags: javascript, charts, google-api, google-visualization

I have a code that draws the following chart: [image: Chart]

As the tittle indicated, I'm looking a way to change the bars colors by their value or range,in the code I made a "dommy" column that indicates the shift of an employee (1 to 3), the employee shift it's sorted.

basically made a stacked column/bar chart in Google Charts that shows the employee sales and the total sorted by their shift(1 to 3).

```
 var dataE = [
        ['EMP', 'CONT', 'CRE', {
          role: 'annotation' //total
        }, {
          role: 'annotation' //employee shift
        }],
        ['Aram', 20500, 12800, '', '3'],
        ['Perry', 36900, 25600, '', '2'],
        ['Tommy', 73000, 75000, '', '1'],
        ['Chris', 70500, 37000, '', '3'],
        ['Francis', 70500, 37000, '', '1'],
        ['Ashley', 70500, 47000, '', '1'],
        ['Cindy', 70500, 37000, '', '2'],
      ];
```

the full code for the chart is here: [FullCode](http://jsfiddle.net/470gmfs6/103)

Comment: you can use a style column role (`{role: 'style'}`) to set a specific color to a bar, similar to how you've used the annotation column role. just add another column with the color name -- [stylerole](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole)